# Group by using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have data

```
ID_panel                               id_vk    Profile       Audio        Video
03a63f1c5a89fb89fcc4d7cf60e2e6b1    100334438                                1
1ea192ddd5c042d71910de18595553a5    100897602                               0.25
1ea192ddd5c042d71910de18595553a5    123581809                               0.35
0038ccb3a47d51a68de51ffeb9607906    35226722    0.058823529
03a63f1c5a89fb89fcc4d7cf60e2e6b1    100334438   0.003552398
03a63f1c5a89fb89fcc4d7cf60e2e6b1    117790896   0.011545293
18441890537f6d9a0559a5f44c28ff67    39356974                  0.974025974
1ea192ddd5c042d71910de18595553a5    123581809                    0.15
```

Desire output:

```
ID_panel                               id_vk    Profile       Audio        Video
03a63f1c5a89fb89fcc4d7cf60e2e6b1    100334438   0.003552398                  1
                                    117790896   0.011545293
1ea192ddd5c042d71910de18595553a5    100897602                               0.25
                                    123581809                  0.15         0.35
0038ccb3a47d51a68de51ffeb9607906    35226722    0.058823529
18441890537f6d9a0559a5f44c28ff67    39356974                  0.974025974
```

I try to use

```
print df.groupby(['ID_panel', 'id_vk'])['Profile', 'Audio', 'Video'].apply(lambda x: "{%s}" % ', '.join(x))
```

But it returns

```
0038ccb3a47d51a68de51ffeb9607906  13312        {Profile, Audio, Video}
                                  35226722     {Profile, Audio, Video}
03a63f1c5a89fb89fcc4d7cf60e2e6b1  795020       {Profile, Audio, Video}
                                  2412315      {Profile, Audio, Video}
```

Not numbers. I write `%s` but `%f` returns `error`

But It does't work and I have an error. How can I do it with my data?

Comment: Don't you mean `df.groupby('ID_panel', 'id_vk')['Profile', 'Audio', 'Video'].sum()`? also what are the `dtype`s here? edit your question with the output from `df.info()`

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I don't understand what I should edit. I want to union string, where `ID_panel` and `id_vk` is equal

Comment: ValueError: No axis named id_vk for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#You have to put the column names in a list.
df.groupby(['ID_panel', 'id_vk'])['Profile', 'Audio', 'Video'].count()
```

Comment: Can you see desire output in the question?

Comment: @hellmoore you have edited your question too much, and the original bug that Abbas solved here is gone. You should clearly mark your second problem as an edit.

Comment: @hellmoore why do you no longer use `count()`?

Comment: I should use `sum` to solve my qestion, thank you! I got what I want